# Blinking folder with question mark while booting

Tags: macos

Whenever I start my Mac, a blinking folder with a question mark appears.

I searched in google and it says to go do " Internet Recovery". I did all the steps, I repaired everything in Disk Utility, then I went ahead and tried to install macOS Sierra, I inserted a flash drive and followed the instructions in Disk Utility.

After that, I went ahead and installed macOS Sierra. Then the prompt appeared which says "You may not install to this volume because the computer is missing a Firmware partition."

So I went ahead and tried to find other ways, the instructions that I followed was: erase the "macOS base system" but mine was all greyed out even the unmount button 
Also, I tried <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and a NVRAM-reset: <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> but they both didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This is a common problem and can be caused by a variety of issues.  This has been asked & answered dozens of times on this site.  You can use the search bar at the top of the page to find the answers already provided.  As currently written, I've voted to have your question closed as a duplicate of one of previously-written questions.

Comment: Please install (in Internet Recovery Mode) a full system to an empty flash drive (at least 32 GB of size) or another empty external drive. After configuring user/network etc. install TeamViewer (a remote desktop app which allows me to check your Mac personally from remote) and send the credentials presented by TeamViewer (ID and password) to klanomath(at)googlemail.com.